# Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mutation.create in typegraphql with bcrypt

Tags: typescript, bcrypt, typeorm, typegraphql

I am trying typegraphql with apollo-server, typeorm, bcrypt with the below resolver in typescript. When the mutation query is run it throws the error 'Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mutation.create'. But it is saving the data to database with hashed password (also i can infer this for sure by using console.log); Only the mutation query is throwing error in browser.

Here is mutation resolver:

```
@Mutation(returns => Users)
create(@Arg("newuser") newuser: UserInput): Promise<Users> | any {
  bcrypt.hash(newuser.loginpassword, 12)
  .then( hash => {
      const new_user = this.usersRepository.create(newuser);
      new_user.loginpassword = hash;
      return this.usersRepository.save(new_user);
    });
}
```

Same when bcrypt related stuff is commented out like below, returns no errors (of-course the password is not hashed)

```
@Mutation(returns => Users)
create(@Arg("newuser") newuser: UserInput): Promise<Users> | any {
  // bcrypt.hash(newuser.loginpassword, 12)
  // .then( hash => {
      const new_user = this.usersRepository.create(newuser);
      //new_user.loginpassword = hash;
      return this.usersRepository.save(new_user);
    //});
}
```

In both the cases, mutation is able to create the record and save them; Also hash is successfully generated with bcrypt code.

I am trying to solve this for last 2 weeks, searching here ([Graphql, node.js and sql,Cannot return null for non-nullable field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54685681/graphql-node-js-and-sql-cannot-return-null-for-non-nullable-field) and many similar) for clues to solve this.

1. What is wrong in first version (that is with bcrypt code included) I have tried changing the return type to Users | any from Promise | any, and adding one more .then statement returning the Users object instead of promise object?
2. Also in [Graphql, node.js and sql,Cannot return null for non-nullable field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54685681/graphql-node-js-and-sql-cannot-return-null-for-non-nullable-field), Mr. Benjie is hinting at https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/why-nullable/#nulls-in-graphql. But I am absolutely clueless how to write nullable Mutation.create. Can someone hint or point to an example or such pattern, pls ?
3. If I keep the create's return declaration to 'Promise<Users>' instead of 'Promise<Users> | any', typescript is not happy and is expecting a return statement. But if I add return statement at the end, create will simply return immediately. So, is the return declaration as 'Promise<Users> | any' is the proper way?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not positive, but I see a few things that might be causing this.

1. In your first code snippet, the only return statement is inside the callback function passed to `then`. So the `create` method does not return anything.
2. I looked at the src for typeORM... it looks like `Repository.save()` returns `Promise<Entity>` (not `Promise<Entity[]>`) when the input value is a single entity object ([see Repository.ts](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/1c09dc31f3e4d64657bf711228741ae7b10f4088/src/repository/Repository.ts#L144)). If this is the case, your GraphQL schema would be expecting this mutation to return an array of users, but the resolver is returning a single user.

Try changing the return type to `Promise<User>`

```js
@Mutation(returns => User)
create(@Arg("newuser") newuser: UserInput): Promise<User> {
  return bcrypt.hash(newuser.loginpassword, 12)
  .then( hash => {
      const new_user = this.usersRepository.create(newuser);
      new_user.loginpassword = hash;
      return this.usersRepository.save(new_user);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Luke. Yes, returning the entire chain starting at bcrypt.hash ... solved the issue. Btw, entity name itself is Users. So it is Promise<Users>. Answer is accepted and thanks a lot.